# Jquery Parse Json on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I trie to get an json in my jquery ajax successe: to worke but i dose not.......

Thats what i tried to do:

```
$("#addcatform").submit(function() {
  var str = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: str,
    success: function(data){
      var json_x = data;
      alert(json_x.firstName2);
      $('#result').html(json_x.firstName2); 
      $('#result2').html(json_x.b); 
    }
  }); 

  return false;
  event.preventDefault();
}); // submit end
```

the php echos this:

```
$arr = array ('firstName2'=>'hallo','b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Whats wrong with this? Thanks for helping!!!!

Comment: Please note that `event` is undefined in your example. You should change the first line to `$("#addcatform").submit( function( event ) {`

Answer (score 8):

You need to parse your json before using it,

You can add a dataType in your request - *jQuery will parse your response json*

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    dataType: 'json',
```

Or, you can parse it yourself -

```
success: function(data){
    var json_x = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad.
If you are gonna parse it by yourself, remember to manage the error thrown if the parse action fails.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
var data=$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {
            data:str
        }, 
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    var msg= data.responseText;
    msg=jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
```

I usually send either an array or the message 'error' from my php page

```
if(msg=='error')
{
/* do something */
}
else
// use the data
```

This works with jquery 1.6->1.8

EDIT:
Since jquery 1.8 async is deprecated. i would recommend this format :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {
            data:str
        }, 
        dataType: 'json',
     ).done(function(data) {
      // do something with the data
     })
   .fail(function() {
    // give appropriate message
    })
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a string in your example. <s>Use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).</s> *Edit: As you cannot do a POST-request with getJSON (dûh) use `.ajax` with the appropiate dataType instead.* This will retrieve the data via ajax, and parses the resulting string as if it is JSON. Even with `getJSON`, the result will be an array (or an array like object, not sure). This has no methods or variables you can access with the dot-notation. You'll need to access it via `data['a']`.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax.php",
  data: str,
  success: function(data){
    var json_x = data;
    alert(json_x['firstName2']);
    $('#result').html(json_x['firstName2']);
    $('#result2').html(json_x['b']); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Correct explanation, but `getJSON` doesn't accept an object as first argument. Have a look at the documentation again.

Comment: You are right; and as he needs a post request... well... he'll need to use .ajax with the appropiate dataType. I believe this will still parse the returned data as if it is JSON.

Comment: At the moment is use  dataType: "json", i get no result without  dataType: "json", i get an alert with undefined...?????????

Comment: Try `console.log( data );` and open your console (F12) to see what data the server sends.

Comment: {"firstName2":"hallo","b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}   thats what i get from the server, but i dont get an output in my site...

Comment: with console.log you can check it's type. The server should send a 'Content-Type: text/json' with the response.

Comment: Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Content-Length 11
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie ...
Host localhost
Referer http://localhost/eventdatenbank3/index.php
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest

Comment: jQuery will not recognize that content type. You'll need to manually parse it then. See pXL's answer.

Comment: when I use this it dosnt worke;(  
dataType: "json", ......
    var json_x = $.parseJSON(data);

I have always tried to set the Content type.. contentType: "application/json",   

but nothing workes